# how to set email id to an ABRecordRef object

Tags: ios, abrecordref

I was manually adding an email id to an ABRecordRef which returns me an exception.Check out the code

```
ABRecordRef person=ABPersonCreate();

NSString *email=@"adsasdads@sadad.com";

ABRecordSetValue(person,kABPersonEmailProperty,(__bridge CFTypeRef)email,NULL);

CFRelease(person);
```

Comment: Which exception on which line ?

Comment: @d-stroyer EXC_BAD_ACCES on ABRecordSetValue()..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.....

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef email = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(email,(__bridge CFTypeRef)emailaddress,kABWorkLabel, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(self.persons,kABPersonEmailProperty,email, NULL);
CFBridgingRelease(email);
```